# Установка Git на MacOS

Tags: mac, git

Устанавливаю GIT (скачанный от сюда http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer) на MacOS.При создании репозитория через терминал git init вылетает следующий текст:

PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH:/opt/local/binexport PATH

git initdyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk  Referenced from: /usr/local/git/bin/git  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk  Referenced from: /usr/local/git/bin/git  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Trace/BPT trap: 5

Подскажите куда копать, гуглин но ничего не нашел:(

Заранее Спасибо!

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/93002/128211

Answer (score 2):

А вы не пробовали установить git через менеджер пакетов [homebrew](http://brew.sh/index_ru.html). Очень просто устанавливаются многие программы.

Answer (score 1):

Можешь [установить MacPorts](https://github.com/macports/macports-base/releases/download/v2.4.2/MacPorts-2.4.2-10.13-HighSierra.pkg), а через него и git:

```
sudo port install git
```